# How to install Pentablet Divers for XP Pen Deco 01 on Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: drivers

How do I install the Pentablet Drivers for XP Pen Deco 01?

I went to the website and downloaded the package (here is the link)

https://www.xp-pen.com/download/index/cid/36.html

I extracted the package but then I cant find the way to install it.

Comment: link does not work

Answer (score 1):

https://www.xp-pen.com/ask/detail/id/220/channel/66.html

1. Connect your XP-Pen product into computer
2. Open driver folder then click right button – Properties on Pentablet_Driver.sh.
3. Go to Permissions tab then make sure enable “Allow executing file as program” function.
4. Run terminal from the folder where is your downloaded extracted driver
5. Run: sudo ./Pentablet_Driver.sh

The command  "sudo ./Pentablet_Driver.sh" needs to be run in terminal everytime after pc or application restarts.

Comment: you can automate the command by creating a [systemd sevice](https://www.devdungeon.com/content/creating-systemd-service-files)

Comment: link does not work

Answer (score 0):

To do more easy to launch the driver create a desktop file in ~/.local/share/applications

The file can named : xp-pen.desktop with its in :

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Exec=pkexec env DISPLAY=$DISPLAY XAUTHORITY=$XAUTHORITY sh -c "/Path/To/Driver/Linux_Pentablet_V1.2.13.1/Pentablet_Driver.sh"
MimeType=application/x-your-mime-type;
Icon=/home/username/.icons/xp-pen.png
X-DocPath=
Terminal=false
Name=XP-Pen
GenericName=XP-Pen
Comment=xp-pen driver for xp-pen pad and pen
Categories=Graphics;2DGraphics;RasterGraphics;Utility;
```

Don't forgot to change "/Path/To/Driver/Linux_Pentablet_V1.2.13.1/" and "username" by yours

Add an icon in ~/.icons named xp-pen.png : https://i.postimg.cc/FzSVY8Vt/xp-pen.png

And after to do it, it's more easy to use the tablet.

For me i add my desktop file in my latte-dock to be more easy to use.

Comment: When app is clicked (from search), it asks for super user permissions (type password), once entered, nothing happens.

Comment: The path to the driver is correct ?

Comment: Yes, in fact I can take the value of Exec and run it in a terminal and it works, but cannot launch using the .desktop

Comment: Facing the same problem here. Nothing happens. Have you solved it?  @ThomasRokicki

Comment: I didn't. I gave up on using the product and threw it in a pile of e-waste. Hope you have more luck than me. @ProtikNag